# Handling state and passing to a component / react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning js and react and still struggle with `useState` and passing information around. What I already have: a list of buttons, that gets filtered based on user text-input. What I need now: upon clicking one of those buttons, it needs to be passed to the next site (home/content). How could I do it? Do I need useState?

Can someone help me? What am I missing?

```
export const content = [
  "Apple",
  "Banana",
  "Blueberry",
  "Cherry",
  "Avocado",
  "Pasta"
];
```

```
export default function BadgeButtonList({ content }) {
  return (
    <BadgeButtonSection>
      {content.map(item => {
        return (
          <BadgeButton list light key={item.name} item={item.toUpperCase()} />
        );
      })}
    </BadgeButtonSection>
  );
}
```

```
export default function Home() {
  const [ searchValue, setSearchValue ] = useState("");
  const [ selectedButton, setSelectedButton] = useState("");

  const history = useHistory();

  const filteredContent = content.filter(item =>
    item.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())
  );

  function handleSearch(value) {
    setSearchValue(value);
  }
  return (
    <WrapperDiv>
            
      <Header />
      <Switch>
                      
        <Route exact path="/home">
                    
          <Searchbar onSearch={handleSearch} />
                    
          <BadgeButtonList
            content={filteredContent}
            onClick={() => {
              setSelectedButton();
              history.push("/home/content");
            }}
          />
                  
        </Route>
                
        <Route exact path="/home/content">
          <BadgeButton light item={selectedButton} />
                             
        </Route>
      </Switch>
                 
    </WrapperDiv>
  );
}
```

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work? What is in the `content` variable?

Answer (score 1):

`useState` [returns an array with two elements only](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#declaring-a-state-variable). The first element is the state value; the second value is the method that sets the value.

You need to change your singular `useState` to two:

```
const [ searchValue, setSearchValue ] = useState('');
const [ selectedButton, setSelectedButton ] = useState('');
```

Comment: You could also use a single `useState` and set it as an object of each property to preserve the current setup. Not sure these solve the issue though since the original problem appears to be not setting the actual value in the child component.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data from one page to another; you can use the `Link` component from react-router. Then you can pass data to another page using `to` prop. The `pathname` is the route you are going to.. Like so:

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/home/content", //the path to your next page
    data: data // pass your data to the next page here
  }}
>
```